# Undefined control sequence \ngtr

Tags: undefined, relation-symbols

I have `\ngtr` in some math mode content, and though the VS Code extension LaTeX Workshop's preview-equation-on-hover functionality displays it correctly, I get an `undefined control sequence` error when trying to build it.

Comment: Many math symbols (including this one) are only defined by packages, and you have to load that package for its name to be recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include this in your preamble:

```latex
\usepackage{amssymb}
```